# node.js to change the color of the form submit button

Tags: css, node.js, bootstrap-4

I use node.js to insert data that I take from an html form into the database. Validation takes place on the server side. I wanted to know if there is a way, to deepen, to make node.js allow me to change the css class associated with the submit data button. That is the green button, it means that the data has been entered without problems, otherwise the button may have a different color depending on the problem encountered.

Answer (score 0):

After submitting you can send response that successful submission.
you can handle the response and if successful then green else red

Comment: yes, I would like to do something like this. It's possible? Generally after filling out a form I change the page. Instead I should be able to send a response and have it examined by javascript if possible.

Comment: yes it possible. first you had prevent the auto refresh page loading and then after receive the data on server and validating the send response

Comment: the client page can change some elements then according to the response of the server?